# Vue js - Getting Methods to work in Components

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a component that passes in data, then I need to change that data from true to false on click. I have created a method called `toggleClass` for that but it's not working, and I am not getting any errors.

```
Vue.component('moustache', {
name: 'moustache',
props: ['type', 'img'],
template: `<li>
    <p><strong>@{{ type }}</strong></p>
    <img width="300" height="200" src="/img/image.jpg">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" v-bind:class="{ active: isActive }" :data-type="type" @click="toggleClass">Vote</button>
    </li>`,
data: function(){
    return{
        isActive: false
    }
},
methods: {
    toggleClass(){
            isActive: true
    }
}
});

new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `this` so that you can access the component properies:

```
toggleClass(){
     this.isActive = !this.isActive;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a winner :)

Answer (score -1):

That's not how toggleClass works, there must be a command for this argument, you need to set it to true in the parameters else it will get stuck on the argument.

Could you try

```
methods: {
    toggleClass(true){
       //     isActive: true
    }
}
});
```

Comment: Sorry mate that throws errors. Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token true